# jQuery animate height step by step

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

My current script works fine, where then 3 menu buttons (menubtn1, menubtn2, menubtn3) make the container change height.
What I would like to do is have the script first animate the height to 0px, then animate to their respective heights.

That way I can replace the content of my container when the height=0px, and then whe it scales back up, the new content will be visible.

here is my script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".menubtn1").click(function() {
        $(".container").stop().animate({
            height: '350px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuint'
        })
    });
    $(".menubtn2").click(function() {
        $(".container").stop().animate({
            height: '200px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuint'
        })
    });
    $(".menubtn3").click(function() {
        $(".container").stop().animate({
            height: '185px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuint'
        })
    });

});​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/craigzilla/RpzpZ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your content in the 'complete' callback function, then animate it again:

```
$(".container").stop().animate({height:0},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeInOutQuint', complete: function(){
    $(this).html('your content').animate({height:350},600);
}})
```

I updated your fiddle as well :)
http://jsfiddle.net/RpzpZ/3/

Here's another variant. That's probably how i would do it.
I added the content directly in the html.
I don't know if you need the fixed heights of the different contents, here i used slideUp and Down so it will always adjust to the height of the content

http://jsfiddle.net/RpzpZ/5/

Comment: This works like a charm.
Is it possible to load a DIV instead of 'your content'?

Comment: The code looks a lot tidier now, but I unfortunately can't figure it out :)
I simply can't see where I can add my different "content" codes?

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen how do you have your different contents? are they hidden divs on the page already or do you want them to load via ajax?

Comment: Yes, I will do hidden divs. 

The first update you did allowed me set the container height at opx so that nothing was visible until I click a button. Is this also possible with the new update?

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen Ah yes, i manually showed the first content in the last css statement: `.container>div:first-child{ display:block; }`. Just delete that and nothing is visible at the start.

Comment: If I remove the mentioned CSS line, then the script doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen Ohh i'm sorry my bad. My script relies on one element being visible. It slides up the visible one then shows the next one. Now if nothing is visible it can't get to the show part. This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/RpzpZ/6/

Comment: I have just tested the jsfiddle and it works perfectly!
The only problem is that it won't work locally?

Comment: I didn't know where to paste my code, so here it is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QzMtAk8H1PHoZg1JaKYYoVY1jyCjz6DJg_taeDFvHjY/edit

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen strange. if i paste and save your code into notepad it says it contains some unicode characters which can't be saved. if i paste it in notepad++ the end of the <script> block looks like this: `})
;?</script>`. if i remove the `?` it works. Try saving it in notepad, then reopen it and remove the additional `?`s

Answer (score 1):

You could use [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) instead of using `.animate()`, like this:

```
$(".container")
   .slideUp("slow", function () {
      $(this)
          .html("<p>New content</p> and some other stuff")
          .slideDown("slow");
   });
```

**Edit**

Updated the example to use the slideUp-callback to change the content and then slide it down again.

Comment: The content will be set at the start of the slideUp in that case.

Comment: @Andy Of course, sorry about that, updated my answer to use the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Could just add a callback function to your animate call which calls another animate function that opens the container back up.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this ->

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#menubtn1").click(function() {
        $(".container").animate({height:"0px"},  function () {
            $("#hidden-content").hide();
            $("#show-content").show( function () {
                $(".container").animate({height:"200px"})   
            });
        });
    });
});
```